# Cost (%CPU) around the same after denormalization?

Tags: sql, oracle, denormalization, denormalized

Using SQL Oracle. I create a query to find the total counts of orders for food.

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT FOOD.F_NAME, COUNT(ORDERS.O_ORDERID)
FROM ORDERS
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON O_CUSTID = C_CUSTID
INNER JOIN FOOD ON C_FOODKEY = F_FOODKEY
GROUP BY FOOD.F_NAME;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

This returns cost (%CPU) of `3250` at row ID 0 in the plan table output.

I learnt that denormalization will speed up the query and reduce the cost. In this case, I copied the food name from my table `FOOD` to `ORDERS` to avoid the `INNER JOIN`. I should get a better cost (%CPU) usage.

I used this query next

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
SELECT ORDERS.F_NAME, COUNT(ORDERS.O_ORDERID)
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY ORDERS.F_NAME;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
```

The cost (%CPU) did not change much at all - the value is `3120` at row ID 0 in the plan table output.

Isn't denormalization and removal of the `INNER JOIN` suppose to improve my cost? The improvement is so insignificant in my case. What's the issue here?

Comment: The second query doesn't look quite right. How can you select `FOOD.F_NAME` if the `FOOD` table is not part of the query?

Comment: My bad! Editing mistake. I have correct it to the correct table.

Comment: Please, post your plans. It may depend on many parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  You would have to study the execution plan.  However, joins on primary keys are often not particularly expensive.

What is expensive is the `GROUP BY`, because this requires moving data around.  You could try adding an index on `F_NAME` in the second query.

Your data model is also unusual.  It is unclear why a column called `FOOD` would be stored at the `CUSTOMER` level.

Answer (score 0):

`C_FOODKEY` should be most likely `O_FOODKEY` to make sense

You do not need denormalization. What you are doing is - you explode all the rows by joins and then you group them together. Do not do this in the first place and try something like this

```
SELECT FOOD.F_NAME, 
      (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM ORDERS 
       WHERE O_FOODKEY = F_FOODKEY) AS fCount
FROM FOOD
```